# Rows of A are linearly independent. Then there exists B such that AB = I

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose rows of matrix $A_{m\times n}$ are linearly independent. Prove that there exists
matrix $B_{n\times m}$ such that $AB = I_{m\times m}$.

Well, basically it's asked to prove that there exists a right inverse of $A$, but I don't understand how'd I do that. I tried to prove it using elementary transformation matrices, but had no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rows are independent $\implies$ $m\le n$, and you can "complete" the matrix $A$ to a $n\times n$ matrix $A'$ with maximum rank and so invertible. There exists the inverse of $A'$, denote it by $B'$ (always $n\times n$), $A'B'=I_{n\times n}$.
Take $B$ the $n\times m$ matrix composed of the first $m$ columns of $B'$.

This is the situation:
$$
A'=
\begin{pmatrix}
A\\
*
\end{pmatrix},\quad
B'=
\begin{pmatrix}
B&
*
\end{pmatrix},
\quad
A'B'=
\begin{pmatrix}
AB&*\\
*&*
\end{pmatrix}
=I_{n\times n}=
\begin{pmatrix}
I_{m \times m}&0\\
0&I_{n-m\times n-m}
\end{pmatrix}.$$

The matrix $B$ is the matrix you are looking for.

Comment: "The" is misleading. There are lots of such $B$'s to be obtained in this way.